# PyQt - what if you do not call .show()

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
label = QLabel("<font color=red size=40>Hello World!</font>")
# label.show()
app.exec()
```

What actually happens if you do not call `label.show()`?
I see that the window does not appear but . . .

Is there a way to direct a "close window event" to the non-shown window?

Comment: Not all things are thread-safe in qt, but [`QApplication.quit()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#quit) may be called from another thread while `.exec()` is running in the main thread. Calling `.show()` only deals with visibility... the window is fully constructed in the background, but just not put on the display.

Comment: @Aaron That's not completely true: the widget is fully constructed only as soon as it's actually shown the first time, or, at least, when it's polished by the style and any layout manager that interacts with it is activated.

Comment: Can you explain why you're asking this and why you need to "direct a close event"?

Comment: @musicamante this is to further my understanding of PyQt and windowing systems.

Comment: Ok, but you didn't explain what you mean by "direct a close window event" and why you want to do that with a not yet shown window.

Comment: Actually this is an interesting question, I sometimes don't call show when I am running unit tests... Is there any particular reason why I shouldn't do that?  I don't think I have ever come across a case where the testcase fails when the widget is rendered and succeeds when it isn't.  @musicamante  and the tests run much quicker when the display isn't rendered.

Comment: @Alexander I've to admit, I've never done unit testing (I don't really need them for my needs, at least right now), so I'm not completely sure about the behavior of PyQt/PySide test environments. I can *assume* that they do consider these aspects and call the required functions, but I don't really know for sure. For instance, widgets *always* have a default size of 640x480 (or 100x30 if created with a parent) when they haven't been shown yet. And, except for explicit size restraints, that won't change until the widget is "mapped" (shown), it's been polished, and/or its layout is activated.

Comment: @musicamante  Thanks.  Good info to know.  Typically the tests I run test functionality of signals, custom models, views and methods, so a widgets size isn't usually a factor.